# ubuntu 18.04 freezes after one minute

Tags: 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04 freezes after one minute.

Recovers after install input attach, then freezes again.

Any help out there ?

Comment: Can you add more information about your issue? How did you get it, what had you done on your computer before getting this error (update, install / unistall any software, modify any system configuration, ...)? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1191549/edit) your question